# On my MVC Web API Put what may be causing an Internal Server Error: 500

Tags: model-view-controller, webapi

I am somewhat new to working with MVC Web API and I was excited to get my MVC Web API GET to work, but really frustrated trying to formulate my Web API Put

I tried to create my dataset to be identical to the the but I did add one property, could that be an issue? Also, I noticed that some of my values on my checkboxes and such are returning nulls these are set up in the model as boolean, so I don't know.

Here is my Web API put

```
// PUT: api/Datasets/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutDataset(int id, Dataset dataset)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != dataset.Dataset_ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(dataset).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!DatasetExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

Here is my HttpPost from my form with my datamodel

[HttpPost]

```
 public ActionResult TestDataset(Dataset dataset)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
        
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4251/");

        //HTTP POST
        
        var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Dataset>("api/datasets/1", dataset);
        postTask.Wait();

        var result = postTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");

    return View(dataset);
}
```

This is my dataset.cs created from Entity Framework on my Web API Project

```
public partial class Dataset
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Dataset()
        {
            this.Attachment = new HashSet<Attachment>();
            this.Contact = new HashSet<Contact>();
            this.Location1 = new HashSet<Location>();
        }
    
        public int Dataset_ID { get; set; }
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Institution { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Domestic { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> International { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Includes_PHI { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> PHI_Limited { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Includes_PIL { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> PIL_Limited { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Citation_Requirements { get; set; }
        public string Citation_Comments { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Availability_Beg_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Availability_End_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Subscription_Renewal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Subscription_Renewal_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Retention_Expiry { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Retention_Expiry_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Data_Destruction { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Destruction_DT { get; set; }
        public string Data_Destruction_Instructions { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Contract_ID { get; set; }
        public bool Draft_Status { get; set; }
        public bool Admin_Only { get; set; }
        public string Dataset_Alias { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Amazon { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_IT_Research { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Research_Proj { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Secure_Data { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Mercury { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Research_CC { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Research_VM { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_External { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Url { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Download_App { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Lab_Terminal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Email_Req { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_File_Download { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Other { get; set; }
        public string Location_Notes { get; set; }
        public string Access_Notes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Added { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Modified { get; set; }
        public string Added_By_User { get; set; }
        public string Updated_By_User { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> External_Collaborators { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
        public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Location1 { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the model I am returning:

```
 public class Dataset
    {
        public int Dataset_ID { get; set; }
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Institution { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Domestic { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> International { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Includes_PHI { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> PHI_Limited { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Includes_PIL { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> PIL_Limited { get; set; }

       
        public Nullable<bool> Citation_Requirements { get; set; }
        public string Citation_Comments { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Availability_Beg_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Availability_End_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Subscription_Renewal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Subscription_Renewal_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Retention_Expiry { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Retention_Expiry_DT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Data_Destruction { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Destruction_DT { get; set; }
        public string Data_Destruction_Instructions { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Contract_ID { get; set; }
        public bool Draft_Status { get; set; }
        public bool Admin_Only { get; set; }
        public string Dataset_Alias { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Amazon { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_IT_Research { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Research_Proj { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Secure_Data { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Mercury { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Research_CC { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_Research_VM { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Loc_External { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Url { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Download_App { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Lab_Terminal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Email_Req { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_File_Download { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Access_Other { get; set; }
        public string Location_Notes { get; set; }
        public string Access_Notes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Added { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Modified { get; set; }
        public string Added_By_User { get; set; }
        public string Updated_By_User { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> External_Collaborator { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Find out the error message behind the 500 error. You can do this by stepping through your code and inspecting the error... i.e. some line in your PUT code is throwing an error and you need to find out what that error is

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid is there a place to look specifically in the response error. Also, I notice that the model I am passing to the view and returning through the post, is missing or nullfying KEYs to the database I am trying to update. I may try to put the key into a hidden field on the View to see if returns, this is so frustrating

Comment: Turning on detailed error messages should show the underlying error https://forums.iis.net/t/1226780.aspx?500+Internal+server+error+how+to+debug+

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I just wanted to let you know I figured out what was causing the Internal Server Error 500, it was a null value being returned to a sql table field that was NOT null.

Comment: I'm pleased you worked it out. It's important to learn how to debug and capture the underlying error message. If you could've found the underlying message it would have shown a database error indicating that a NULL value was the issue.